# Dynamic 365 - Retrieve API Metadata Attribute List - DateTimeBehavior

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics-crm-webapi

We have started using Dynamic API to retrieve an entity's attribute list for migration purposes as below:

```
GET [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='contact')?$select=LogicalName,AttributeOf,AttributeType HTTP/1.1  
Accept: application/json  
OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
OData-Version: 4.0
```

For "*DateTime*" AttributeType field, there is a property within its calls **DateTimeBehavior** which has a "*DateOnly*" Value:

```
"DateTimeBehavior": {
  "Value": "DateOnly"
}
```

We need to know this to convert the legacy data to either DateTime or Date field. However, if we include **DateTimeBehavior** into the $select of our GET api call, we will get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "0x0",
    "message": "Could not find a property named 'DateTime' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.AttributeMetadata'."
  }
}
```

So we're stuck doing separate call for each "*DateTime*" AttributeType field to discover if it's a "*DateOnly*" or not.

Is there a way I can $select all attributes within an entity and include this "*DateOnly*" field if it's exists?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe so. [In order to retrieve the properties of a specific type of attribute you must cast the Attributes collection-valued navigation property to the type you want.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-metadata-web-api#querying-entitymetadata-attributes)

However, you can get back ALL the datetime attributes with their appropriate `DateTimeBehavior` for an entity/table at once (vs. querying each attribute one at a time).

```
GET /api/data/v9.0/EntityDefinitions(LogicalName='account')/Attributes/Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.DateTimeAttributeMetadata?$select=LogicalName,DateTimeBehavior
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, that's my workaround atm, glad to confirm that there is no other way